# Tomcat Websocket closes connection (CLOSED_ABNORMALLY) after sending message

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

My code sends a message and within 100 ms, the onClosed() gets called with CloseReason  CLOSED_ABNORMALLY An unrecoverable IOException occurred so the connection was closed

Comment: ...and, can you also post your source code?

Comment: Thanks. I found out the problem. The issue was in the message handler when i was parsing the message into a json, there was a unhandled parsing exception. And that caused the IOException which caused session to close. I dont like that the session gets closed, but that's what it was. Once i handled the exception, i got the session to stay open.

Comment: @justAnotherGuy - FYI - If you are new to S.O., it uses a Q&A (question and answer) model, so things work a little differently than in a discussion forum.  As written, the question is a little ambiguous. Could you expand it to better describe the process and issue? Since it sounds like you were able to resolve it, feel free to post a separate "answer", explaining the solution (answering your own question is allowed on S.O.). That way A) folks can up vote it and B) the clear question and answer (solution) will help the next guy that runs into the same issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the issue.

The issue was in the message handler (onMessage()).
While parsing the response into a json, there was a unhandled parsing exception. That caused an IOException to be thrown which caused the session to close.
It is unintuitive that the session gets closed, while there is no meaningful indication that the IOException happened inside the onMessage().
Once i handled the exception, the session stays open.